# Invoice Date needs to be static

Tags: message-templates, invoice

I need our invoice date to be static not the date I print it.  Is there a token or some other way of achieving this please.  We plan to use invoices in civi for all contributions - via payment processor and BACs pending.

I can see there’s a receipt date and a received date.  Is there any date field that is a created date?  I really want to use civi for this but it needs to work in a way that doesn’t require too much user adaption.

I have changed the system workflow invoice template so it suits our needs but I’m stuck on this one.  I have seen a thread about this but it doesn’t quite answer the how to for me [How do I print the "received date" on an invoice?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/q/21128/7191)

I mean that I would like to have the invoice date always show the date the invoice is issued.  The contribution invoice date is the date it is printed or emailed which isn’t acceptable as any invoice needs to have the same date  it started with, not one that changes every time it’s printed or emailed.

Thanks in advance

Comment: linking to the other thread would help others avoid repeating such advice.

Comment: also, for clarity sake, you say 'needs to be static' but then seem to say 'created date'. can you add more to your Question to explain exactly what you are after

Comment: As requested I’ve added further info

Comment: can you provide the path that you are using to access the Invoice to edit it? do you have Tax/Invoice enabled at civicrm/admin/setting/preferences/contribute?reset=1?have you already access the Invoice msg tpl at civicrm/admin/messageTemplates?reset=1 (under System Workflow Messages), if so have you already tried the fix offered by Jaap in the other Q+A that you linked to , namely replacing with $contribution.receive_date

Comment: I've customised the template from system workflow and all is working we.  I can use the receive date however when adding a new contribution - the assuption is that the date received is the date the contribution was received (eg via BACS etc) and that's what users expect that to be.  We don't do all transactions through a payment processor so we have to manually enter that date for our BACS member subs.

Comment: We use that date to calculate how long they take from invoice due to payment - which can be up to a year and so it's a useful field.  Is there a way to change the Label on that in the New contribution to invoice date? and then it won't confuse the user and we'll have to think of a new way around the issue of the date we receive payment?

Comment: You could try Word Replacement - but i am not really following what you are saying